# Optional IN Clause

Tags: sql, t-sql

If you have something like below

```
SELECT column1
FROM table1
WHERE id IN (SELECT column2 FROM table2 WHERE id2 = 'x')
```

I have a scenario where the in clause may not return any data which means I should get all the data and not 0 rows as though the in clause was never created. I cannot do joins either.

Comment: You're saying you need to evaluate the subquery, see if it returns 0 rows, and if it does - then you should not use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
select column1 from table1 
where    id in (select column2 from table2 where id2 = 'x') 
      OR IF NOT EXISTS (select column2 from table2 where id2 = 'x')
```

This will use the ID in clause if rows returned, but ignore it if 0 rows.

Caveat: I don't know the performance implications of larger data sets and how the query optimizer would execute this.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this, using a CTE (common table expression)

```
with filter  as
(
  select distinct
         t2.column2 as id
  from table2 t2
  join table1 t1 on t1.id = t2.column2
                and t2.id2 = 'x'
)
select t1.*
from      table1 t1
left join filter f  on f.id = t1.id
where f.id is not null                    -- matched the filter
   OR 0 = ( select count(*) from filter ) -- filter is empty
```

Answer (score 0):

What database are you working in?

You can do this in SQL Server (but then again, you can do joins in SQL Server):

```
IF EXISTS (select column2 from table2 where id2 = 'x')
BEGIN
    select column1 from table1 where id in (select column2 from table2 where id2 = 'x')
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    select column1 from table1
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I thing this will do the trick
If I understand what you are looking for

```
select column1 
  from table1 
  left join table2 
    on table1.id = table2.colum2 
 where table2.colum2 = 'x'
    or table2.colum2 is null
```

TLDR  Why can you not do joins?

Not sure if they syntax works but something like this
Again why can you not do joins?
But with this approach the answer from Martin is better

```
where id in (select column2 from table2 where id2 = 'x') 
   or (select count(*) from table2 where id2 = 'x') = 0
```